# uWSGI won't find a module that exists in all python installations

Tags: python, django, uwsgi, python-3.6

I am trying to run a Django app through uWSGI on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch), it came with Python 3.5 from the distro and I compiled and installed Python 3.6 as an alternative. These are my current Python installations:

- Python 2: /usr/bin/python
- Python 3.5: /usr/bin/python3.5
- Python 3.6: /usr/local/bin/python3.6

I also created a virtualenv based on `python3.6` for my app located at `~/.virtualenvs`. The problem is that the service complains about not being able to get the locale encoding:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding

Because of a missing module:

> ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

However, if I start my virtualenv and issue:

```
import encodings
```

It works completely fine:

```
>>> import encodings
>>> encodings
<module 'encodings' from '/home/ariel/.virtualenvs/you2ogg/lib/python3.6/encodings/__init__.py'>
```

This is how my `service.ini` file looks like:

```
[uwsgi]

plugins = python3

chdir = /srv/user/app/
module = app.wsgi
home = /home/user/.virtualenvs/app/

master = true

processes = 10

socket = /srv/user/app/app.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

uid = 1000
gid = 1000
```

And this is what the logs say about my service:

```
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14-debian (32bit) on [Wed Dec 20 11:29:49 2017] ***
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - compiled with version: 6.2.1 20161124 on 18 December 2016 15:05:38
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - os: Linux-4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - nodename: rpi3
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - machine: armv7l
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - clock source: unix
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - pcre jit disabled
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - detected number of CPU cores: 4
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - current working directory: /
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/you2ogg/pid
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - setgid() to 1000
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - setuid() to 1000
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - chdir() to /srv/ariel/you2ogg/
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - your processes number limit is 7346
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/you2ogg/socket fd 3
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /srv/ariel/you2ogg/you2ogg.sock fd 5
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - Python version: 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170124]
Wed Dec 20 11:29:51 2017 - Set PythonHome to /home/ariel/.virtualenvs/you2ogg/
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x76f35000 (most recent call first):
```

Note, though, that apparently uWSGI insists on using Python 3.5 for who-knows-what and according to some other questions setting PYTHONPATH solves this issue, however I have to note that this app runs completely fine on a Fedora machine, where that var isn't set either.

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found what the problem was. It turns out that the python plugin for uWSGI is somehow bound to a python version, e.g.:

- python → python2.7
- python3 → python3.5

So I had to compile and manually install my plugin for Python 3.6 by following [this guide](http://www.paulox.net/2017/04/04/how-to-use-uwsgi-with-python3-6-in-ubuntu/):

```
PYTHON=python3.6 uwsgi --build-plugin "/usr/src/uwsgi/plugins/python python36"
mv python36_plugin.so /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python36_plugin.so
chmod 644 /usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/python36_plugin.so
```

It now shows Python 3.6.X as the Python version on the uWSGI service init log and the app works correctly. The reason it worked in Fedora may be because since Fedora 26 it comes with Python 3.6 as the default python3 version, so perhaps the plugin is compatible out-of-the-box.

Comment: I was getting the exact same error as you were:  `Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'`.  Your answer led me to the solution.